# Link Author URL's based on a custom field

Tags: wp-query, user-roles

I'm querying a custom field of users based on a city they are in.  I am able to display their profile photo and display name, however I can't seem to get the link to their actual author url to work.

It just keeps linking to the same page it's currently on.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
        $london_args = array(   
            'meta_value'   => 'London',
        );

        // The Query
        $london_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $london_args );

        // User Loop
        if ( ! empty( $london_user_query->results ) ) {
            foreach ( $london_user_query->results as $user ) {

        ?>


            <li>    
                <?php if($user->user_cover_pic == '') { ?>
                Photo coming soon
                <?php } else { ?>
                <a href="<?php $user->url; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $user->user_cover_pic; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->display_name; ?>">
                </a>
                <?php }; ?><br>

                <a href="<?php $user->url; ?>"><?php echo $user->display_name; ?></a>
            </li>


        <?php
            }
        } else {

            echo 'No Lawyers found in London.';

        } ?>
```

Comment: Did you want the Author Posts URL? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url , https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure too much about the code but i think you forgot to `echo`  $user->url

So just replace all `$user->url` with `echo $user->url`

Comment: Oh, good find on the echo.  How silly of me to forget to try that.  Unfortunately it is still linking to the same page.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it!

```
echo get_author_posts_url( $user->ID );
```

Thank you for replying, terminator.  :)  You at least got me in the right direction.